# Internet explorer not playing youtube videos with JW Player

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, video, youtube, jwplayer

I am using the latest version of JW Player to render youtube videos to a page, it works great in Chrome and FF but in all versions of IE it just renders a black rectangle with no errors to go on. I am rendering the videos with this code:

```
jwplayer("video3").setup({
   file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxx",
   height: 500,
   width: 736
});
```

What is the issue?

EDIT:

This is the code that the JS generates in IE, if this helps at all:

```
<object name="video1" width="100%" height="100%" tabindex="0" id="video1" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" "=""><PARAM NAME="_cx" VALUE="19473">
  <PARAM NAME="_cy" VALUE="13229"><PARAM NAME="FlashVars" VALUE="">
  <PARAM NAME="Movie" VALUE="http://xxx.xxx/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf">
  <PARAM NAME="Src" VALUE="http://xxx.xxx/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf">
  <PARAM NAME="WMode" VALUE="Opaque"><PARAM NAME="Play" VALUE="0">
  <PARAM NAME="Loop" VALUE="-1"><PARAM NAME="Quality" VALUE="High">
  <PARAM NAME="SAlign" VALUE=""><PARAM NAME="Menu" VALUE="-1">
  <PARAM NAME="Base" VALUE=""><PARAM NAME="AllowScriptAccess" VALUE="always">
  <PARAM NAME="Scale" VALUE="ShowAll"><PARAM NAME="DeviceFont" VALUE="0">
  <PARAM NAME="EmbedMovie" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="BGColor" VALUE="000000">
  <PARAM NAME="SWRemote" VALUE=""><PARAM NAME="MovieData" VALUE="">
  <PARAM NAME="SeamlessTabbing" VALUE="1">
  <PARAM NAME="Profile" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="ProfileAddress" VALUE="">
  <PARAM NAME="ProfilePort" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="AllowNetworking" VALUE="all">
  <PARAM NAME="AllowFullScreen" VALUE="true">
  <param name="movie" value="http://xxx.xxx/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf">
  <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
  <param name="seamlesstabbing" value="true">
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque"><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000">
 </object>
<div id="video1_aspect" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: That should work fine, do you have a link?

Comment: Its a dev site, I am not sure if disclosing that would be wise but I posted the HTML output of the JS in IE if that helps, any ideas?

Comment: Maybe email it? - info [at] longtailvideo [dot] com, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What version of IE. Check [this](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28837/browser-device-support/) to make sure it is supported.

My best guess:
[image]

Comment: Using 10 and 9, thats all. Thoroughly enjoyed the picture haha

Answer (score 0):

Just didnt have flash player installed apparently